# html "id" in actionLink razor helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to specify the html `id` in `ActionLink`, but I can't do this:

```
@html.ActionLink("Controller", "Action", new {@id = "tec"})
```

because the `@id` means that `tec` is a value of `id` parameter.

On the other hand, if I do

```
@html.ActionLink("Controller", "Action", new {@class = "tec"})
```

the result will be:

```
<a href="Controller/Action" class="tec"></a>
```

Do you know a way to specify the html id?

I wanna this result:

```
<a href="Controller/Action" id="tec"></a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specifiy also the controller and you can remove the `@` before id

```
@Html.ActionLink("mylink", "Action", "Controller", new {id = "tec"})
```

That's because the signature you are using is not the one relative to HtmlAttributes, but to the routing values. If you do not want to specify the controller, use this

```
@Html.ActionLink("mylink", "Action", null, new {id = "tec"})
```

Comment: Great! Tks, mas.I Leave an empty space in text Link to show an image as a link: @Html.Action(" ", Action,"Controller", null, new{id="tec"}). It solved my problem! Tks!

Answer (score 1):

The method signature in your case should be of this..

```
   public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Provide the parameters in the same format. htmlattributes should be for creating new html object.